# CartThrob Issue with item_options:input:my_option and certain characters

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, shopping-cart

Haven't been able to get a reply from the guys at CartThrob since November, so hopefully someone here can help out.

We have the following in our add to cart form:

```
{if cf_products_stampinglimit}
 <p>
  <label for="stamping">
   <span class="label">Stamping:</span>
   {item_options:input:stamping type="text" value=""}
   <span class="note">Character limit: {cf_products_stampinglimit}. If you're ordering more than one charm, separate each stamp with a comma.</span>
  </label>
 </p>
{/if}
```

While it works well 99% of the time, I’ve recently discovered that if a customer types something like “a + b” in the field, then the email shows up blank or with this error message:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /my/path/to/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 94`

The field is filled out just fine in the order entry though (i.e., it gets saved just fine). Here’s the code snippet for that piece in the email template:

```
{if "{item:stamping}"}Stamping: <em>{item:stamping}</em><br />{/if}
```

I’ve tested this extensively and the email appears normally unless it has something like “x + x”. Any idea on how to fix this?

Running EE 2.5.2 and CartThrob 2.1.5.

**Update:** We've since upgraded to EE 2.5.5 and CT 2.2.9 and now, instead of getting a blank email, this error is sent instead:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" != "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /path/to/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 81`

Additionally, this is the case for various characters: + & ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this. The issue wasn't even with the `{item:stamping}` field, it was with another one (SKU) that the site manager's fill in. On a few products the SKU included `"` and that's what was causing the problem.

So I simply changed the code to use single quotes and everything is working great:

`{if '{item:cf_products_sku}' != ""}SKU #{item:cf_products_sku}<br />{/if}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using javascript to replace the + with  `&plus;` or `&#43;` before submitting? That section of EE code is encoding the email and calling the typography library, something in there may be choking on the +.

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. Will give it a shot this week. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try the conditional written like any of the following:

```
{if "{item:stamping}" != ""}
```

or

```
{if '{item:stamping}' != ''}
```

or

```
{if {item:stamping} != ""}
```

Comment: Have definitely tried that, doesn't make a difference. :/